# How can i compare the typed word with the word list?

Tags: c

I have to let to user type in a word, like 'Meal'.
In addition i have to have specific arguments(Words) like Meal, Drink, ... which i have to compare with the word the user typed.
I dont exactly know how i can compare the word, which is a char for me with a done list of words.
In the following example i god a program crash:

```
char listing[3];
listing[0]="Meal";
listing[1]="Drink";
listing[2]='\0';
```

I have to compare this list with the typed in word:

```
char option;
printf("Please insert your option");
scanf("%s", &option);
```

Maybe my list is wrong? i just tried to compare it in my function with if, but its not working:

```
if ((option==listing[0]) ||
(option==listing[1]))
```

And if i declare the list with for example "Meal" it says 
warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]|

Thanks for your help, i sadly cant find a solution, shame on me.
Greetz

Comment: and `char* listing[3]`, dont forget the *star*.

Comment: `char listing[3];
listing[0]="Meal";` Attempting to assign 5 characters (MEAL0) to an array of 3 doesn't normally work... (And I'm ignoring the type incompatibility). Looks like you don't know the difference between a `char` and a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `if ((option==listing[0]) || (option==listing[1]))`, use `strcmp`:

`if( (0 == strcmp(option, listing[0])) || ( 0 == strcmp(option, listing[1])) )`

Also, `listing` should be an array of pointers to char.

```
char *listing[2];
listing[0]="Meal";
listing[1]="Drink";
```

Comment: `char option;` is wrong too. May be use something like this `char option[100] = "";`. Also remove `listing[2] = '\0';` (I don't know where you got that from).

Comment: you didn't mention `cMM` in the code, and I see no reason why you'd need that `isalpha(cMM) == 1`. Just use `strcmp` would be ok.